# SharePoint Online - connected documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, powerapp

I need a little guidance/brainstorm with connecting documents from different libraries.

Idea is to have an easy way for user to connect (link) multiple documents to one document. Example would be, I have document A and want to have a connection (links) to documents B,C,E...
Those documents could be in any document libraries.
So, when user opens up document A Propeties/custom spfx form/power app (whatever), he/she can jump to connected documents.

I would probably need two-piece solution:

1. to find document to whom I want to link (search all libraries)
2. to have a view form, so user could Easly check for all the links

Do you have any hints, what would be a good approach to this, create spfx solution, power app, maybe there is some third-party plugin...?

Thanks,
Aleks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom SPFx web part that allows users to search for documents across multiple libraries using SharePoint Search APIs or Microsoft Graph APIs. Users can select the desired documents and establish the connections.

Use SharePoint's built-in document properties to store the connections between documents. You can create a custom field in the document library to store the linked documents' IDs or URLs.

Enhance the document properties/custom form with additional UI elements to display and navigate the connected documents.